# Hashing implementation is working very slowly

Tags: hash, hashmap, hashtable

I am new to hash tables and tried to implement them myself. But my method seems to be working very slowly.

The question was:

*The goal of this problem is to implement a variant of the 2-SUM algorithm covered in this week's lectures.*

*The file contains 1 million integers, both positive and negative (there might be some repetitions!).This is your array of integers, with the ith row of the file specifying the ith entry of the array.*

*Your task is to compute the number of target values t in the interval [-10000,10000] (inclusive) such that there are distinct numbers x,y in the input file that satisfy x+y=t. (NOTE: ensuring distinctness requires a one-line addition to the algorithm from lecture.)*

*Write your numeric answer (an integer between 0 and 20001) in the space provided.*

*OPTIONAL CHALLENGE: If this problem is too easy for you, try implementing your own hash table for it. For example, you could compare performance under the chaining and open addressing approaches to resolving collisions.*

The code I wrote solved the problem in more than 10 minutes!!! I am not able to figure out how I can speed this up.
This is my code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct entry
{
    long long val;
    entry* next;
};

int hf(long long x)
{
    int p= x%2000003;
    if(p>=0)return p;
    return -1*p;
}

void addentry(int y,long long x,vector<long long> arr[])
{
    int flag=0;
    for(long long t:arr[y])
    {
        if(t==x)
        {
            flag=1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
        arr[y].push_back(x);
}

bool isthere(long long x,vector<long long> arr[])
{
    int y=hf(x);
    for(long long t:arr[y])
    {
        if(t==x) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool sd(vector<long long> arr[],int t,int a[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        {
            if((a[i])>=t){continue;}
            if(isthere(t-(a[i]),arr))
            {
                return true;
            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}
int main()
{
    ifstream f("F:\sum1.txt");
    vector<long long> arr[2000003];
    int a[1000007];
    int size=0;
    long long x;
    while(f>>x)
    {
        int y=hf(x);
        addentry(y,x,arr);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<2000003;i++)
    {
        for(long long t:arr[i])
        {
            a[size]=t;
            size++;
        }
    }
    int sum=0;
    for(int t=-10000;t<=10000;t++)
    {
        if(sd(arr,t,a,size))sum++;
    }
    cout<<endl<<sum;
}
```

Can someone please help me with where I'm going wrong or how I can fix this?

EDIT:
I am not using the structure entry and forgot to erase it from the code.

I have used arr as the buckets for hashing and also used another array a to store the distinct elements in the hash table. I have used size to store the number of elements present in the array a.

The function hf takes a number as the input and returns the hash function output of that number.

The function addentry takes the element value, the bucket it belongs to and the array arr representing the hash table and adds that element in the hash table.

The function isthere returns if an element is present in the hash table.

The function sd takes the array arr, the integer t, the array a and the number of unique elements in the hash table size and returns if the sum of any distinct pair of the hash map is t. To avoid repetition and not obtaining the same elements, only the elements which are less than t are checked. For every checked element a[i], the element t-a[i] is searched for i the map.

As suggested by Jim Mischel, I calculated the number of buckets having more than 10 elements. There were no such elements. There were 29 buckets with more than 5 elements. I think with these numbers the hash function is giving any problems. I don't think finding average number of elements in a bucket is useful as it will only depend on the number of distinct elements and number of buckets.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please also provide a little bit more information about your question. Where do you think it's going wrong?

Comment: One thing you should do is analyze the distribution of items in your final hash table. What is the percentage of buckets that is empty? What is the average number of items in each occupied bucket? How many buckets have more than 10 items in them? That kind of thing. It's likely that your hash function, `x%2000003`, isn't giving you a good distribution.

Comment: It also would help if you gave some sense about what your algorithm is doing. Describe in words how your code solves the problem. Cryptic names like `sd` aren't much help to those of us who don't have the context of your problem. Using descriptive variable and function names adds a lot to code readability, and costs you nothing.